# App Crashing - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android

My app is crashing everytime I try to click a button that inputs text into a listView, I am getting the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick"; I've tried other solutions to the problem but I can't seem to find my own solution. Any help is appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
String infoText;
int position;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("started",true);
            if(isFirstStart)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this,Intro.class));
                SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();
                e.putBoolean("started", false);
                e.apply();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,EditMessageClass.class);
            intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_INFO_DATA,arrayList.get(position).toString());
            intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_ITEM_POSITION,position);
            startActivityForResult(intent,Intent_Constants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_2);
        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,EditFieldClass.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,Intent_Constants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode==Intent_Constants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE){
        infoText = data.getStringExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_INFO_FIELD);
        arrayList.add(infoText);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else if(resultCode==Intent_Constants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_2){
        infoText = data.getStringExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_CHANGED_INFO);
        position = data.getIntExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_ITEM_POSITION,-1);
        arrayList.remove(position);
        arrayList.add(position,infoText);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
 }
```

Intent_Constants.java

```
public class Intent_Constants {
public final static int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE=1;
public final static int INTENT_RESULT_CODE=1;
public final static int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_2=2;
public final static int INTENT_RESULT_CODE_2=2;
public final static String INTENT_INFO_FIELD="info_field";
public final static String INTENT_INFO_DATA="info_data";
public final static String INTENT_ITEM_POSITION="item_position";
public final static String INTENT_CHANGED_INFO="changed_info";
```

EditMessageClass.java

```
public class EditMessageClass extends AppCompatActivity {
String infoText;
int position;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_promo_layout);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    infoText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_INFO_DATA);
    position = intent.getIntExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_ITEM_POSITION,-1);
    EditText infoData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.info);
    infoData.setText(infoText);
}

public void saveButtonClicked(View v){
    String changedinfoText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.info)).getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_CHANGED_INFO,changedinfoText);
    intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_ITEM_POSITION, position);
    setResult(Intent_Constants.INTENT_RESULT_CODE_2,intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

EditFieldClass.java

```
public class EditFieldClass extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_promo_layout);
}

public void saveButtonClicked(View v){
    String infoText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.info)).getText().toString();
    if(infoText.equals("")){
    }
    else{
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_INFO_FIELD,infoText);
        setResult(Intent_Constants.INTENT_RESULT_CODE,intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Logs

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: gabriel.com.prototype, PID: 15435
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
    at gabriel.com.prototype.EditFieldClass.saveButtonClicked(EditFieldClass.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Apparently there is no `EditText` with ID `info` in the `add_promo_layout` layout for `EditFieldClass`.

Comment: check for the id or just post `add_promo_layout.xml` also.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logcat message, I can say that your EditText object is `null`
the problem is caused by this line.

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.info)).getText().toString()
```

Make sure you have EditText with id 'info' in `EditFieldClass`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at gabriel.com.prototype.EditFieldClass.saveButtonClicked(EditFieldClass.java:27)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

your EditText is null , **check editText id** .